# Laravel Forge Custom VPS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, forge

I want to provision a new custom vps in Laravel Forge. The client I'm working for only has a cloud server with Ubuntu 18.04 running. The Laravel Forge docs forcing me to use Ubuntu 20.04 - but unfortunately that's not possible at the moment.

Is there any solution to use Laravel Forge with a Ubuntu 18.04 or do we have to move on to a hosting provider who provides Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.
Cheers
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reached out the the Laravel Forge support with the exact same question. The answer is no, you have to upgrade to 20.04.

https://twitter.com/jbrooksuk/status/1263539840878022656